# Why do some web apps append (random?) strings to cookie names?

Tags: web-applications

I've noticed that, for example, WordPress appends what seems to be some kind of hash or random string to its `wordpress_logged_in` cookie, making a cookie name of, for example, `wordpress_logged_in_abcdef1234`, which makes accessing it from within a script less than straightforward.

Could someone please explain why this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cookie Hash

#### Derivation

The appended string is a hash of the site URL; refer to [Understanding Wordpress Auth Cookies](http://www.securitysift.com/understanding-wordpress-auth-cookies/).

> 1) Cookie ID
>
> What I’m calling the auth “cookie ID” is defined in the file
>   default-constants.php:
>
> `if ( !defined('AUTH_COOKIE') )
>        define('AUTH_COOKIE', 'wordpress_'.COOKIEHASH);`
>
> It’s simply a concatenation of “wordpress_” and a value called
>   COOKIEHASH which is also defined in the same file:
>
> `if ( !defined( 'COOKIEHASH' ) ) {
>        $siteurl = get_site_option( 'siteurl' );
>      if ( $siteurl )
>        define ( 'COOKIEHASH', md5( $siteurl ) );
>      else 
>        define ( 'COOKIEHASH', '' );
>   }`
>
> As you can see, COOKIEHASH is  nothing more than an MD5 of your site’s
>   URL.

#### Purpose

As to why this is done, it probably relates to allowing multiple wordpress sites to share a domain name (with the sites in different sub-directories). Without a unique identifier, the sites would keep overriding each others' cookies.